# How to differentiate a exe from VS15 compiled or VS17 compiled

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have an exe which is compiled with either VS15 or VS17 or VS19. This i can say because it links to vcruntime140.dll. I want to know which version is it compiled with.

Is there any way or tool which correctly determines which version of Visual studio is used to compile. I can remove vc redistributibles and see if the exe is running or not, but i want to automate it in my script to determine it.

Thanks for suggestions. Hail the StackOverflow.

Comment: You'll need a tool that shows PE info. You might be able to get some information by uploading to virus total.

Answer (score 0):

The PE info provides the details of the executible. Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification describe in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format can be used to understand the data.

There are many tools like "PEstuido", "EXEInfo PE" which display this data.
Thankyou  @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere.

-Gurudatha